# Decode gzipped JSON in Akka HTTP

Tags: json, scala, akka-http

I have an endpoint we can call `/test` that internally fetches data from a 3rd party API and then wants to do some transformation before returning a response. Where I am hung up is this 3rd party API is returning gzipped JSON and I can't decode it (yet).   I found the [decodeRequest directive](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9-RC2/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/coding-directives/decodeRequest.html#description) but it seems I have to use this in my routing and I am a level deeper here. I have an internal method I call once I receive a `GET` to my endpoint `/test` which is named `do3rdPartyAPIRequest`  where I build up an `HttpRequest` and pass to  `Http().singleRequest()` so then in return I have a `Future[HttpResponse]` which is where I think I want to be but I am stuck here.

With some local APIs I built and consumed in a similar fashion I didn't encode my responses so typically with a `Future[HttpResponse]` I check the response status and go into conversion to JSON via `Unmarshal` but this one needs an extra  step as far as I know before transforming to JSON.  I realize this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515696/spray-unzip-httpresponse) however that is spray specific and I haven't been able to translate this answer into current akka http

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally figured this out - this might not be the absolute best to get a bytestring from response but it works .. Turns out you can use [Gzip class](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4/akka/http/scaladsl/coding/Gzip.html)

and you have two options

1. `Gzip.decode`
2. `Gzip.decoderFlow`

Here are my examples in case this helps you:

```
def getMyDomainObject(resp: HttpResponse):Future[MyDomain] = {
 for {
   byteString <- resp.entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _)
   decompressedBytes <- Gzip.decode(byteString)
   result <- Unmarshal(decompressedBytes).to[MyDomain]
  } yield result
}


def getMyDomainObjectVersion2(resp:HttpResponse):Future[MyDomain] = {
   resp.entity.dataBytes
   .via(Gzip.decoderFlow)
   .runWith(Sink.head)
   .flatMap(Unmarshal(_).to[MyDomain])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would expect that compressed content would be managed by akka-http by default, but it only provides `PredefinedFromEntityUnmarshallers` and inside entity there is not information about `Content-encoding` header.

To solve this you have to implement your own Unmarshaller and to have it in scope

Example:

```
implicit val gzipMessageUnmarshaller = Unmarshaller(ec => {
      (msg: HttpMessage) => {
        val `content-encoding` = msg.getHeader("Content-Encoding")
        if (`content-encoding`.isPresent && `content-encoding`.get().value() == "gzip") {
          val decompressedResponse = msg.entity.transformDataBytes(Gzip.decoderFlow)
          Unmarshal(decompressedResponse).to[String]
        } else {
          Unmarshal(msg).to[String]
        }
      }
    })
```